# How can i fix my code so i can read my data

Tags: angular, rxjs, chart.js

Running this code (below) is giving me this error message :

```
TypeError: res.rates.pipe is not a function
    at SafeSubscriber._next (area.component.ts:35)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:185)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:124)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at CatchSubscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at CatchSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at TapSubscriber._next (tap.js:46)
    at TapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:6014
```

Property Alloc does not exist on type unknown

My component code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartsModule} from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts'
import * as Chart from 'chart.js';
import { AreaService } from './area.service';
import { IArea } from './area';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-widget-area',
  templateUrl: './area.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./area.component.scss']
})
export class AreaComponent implements OnInit {

  area:IArea[];  
  httpService: any;
  LineChart: Chart;
  errorMessage:string;
  Date1;
  Alloc;
  constructor(private _areaService:AreaService) { }
   ngOnInit() {
    this._areaService.getArea().subscribe(
     res => {
        this.Alloc = res['rates'].pipe(map(res => res.Alloc))
      })
     this.LineChart = new Chart('lineChart', {
        type: 'line',
        data: { 
           labels: ["2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019"],
            datasets: [{
            data: this.Alloc,
            fill:false,
            lineTension:0.2,
            borderColor:"blue",
            borderWidth: 1

          },

        ]

      },

        options: {
          legend:{
            display: false
          },
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              display: true
            }],
             yAxes: [{
               display:true
             }]

        }
      }
    })

}
  createChart() {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }

}
```

my service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators'; 
import { IArea } from './area';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AreaService {



  private areaUrl = 'assets/rates.json'



  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getArea(): Observable<IArea[]> {
      return this.http.get<IArea[]>(this.areaUrl).pipe(tap(res => res),

          catchError(this.handleError)
        );
    }
    private handleError(err:HttpErrorResponse){
      // in a real world app, we may send the server to some remote logging infrastructure
    // instead of just logging it to the console
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;
    }
    console.error(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }

}
```

My data is simply numbers that correspond with the years:

```
{"rates":[

      {
      "Alloc": 23

      },
      {
      "Alloc": 20
    },
    {
      "Alloc": 30
    },
    {
      "Alloc": 40
    },
    {
      "Alloc": 24
    },
    {
      "Alloc": 23
    },
    {
      "Alloc": 23
    },
    {
      "Alloc": 56
    },
    {
      "Alloc": 32
    },
    {
      "Alloc": 34
    },
    {
      "Alloc": 34
    }
  ]}
```

tried running it with map but that is not working either. I have rxjs imported, i am not sure what to do fix this issue so my data is plotted on the graph.

Answer (score 1):

`pipe` is a method of Observables, it is for chaining observable operators. You have to use it on an Observable before calling `subscribe`.

In your case a plain JavaScript `this.Alloc = res.rates.map((e) => e.Alloc);` might be enough.

Comment: I am getting the error: property 'rates' does not exist on type IArea[ ] in the service.ts

Comment: and i called pipe in observable before using it in subscribe.